# Selectize (.js) and external source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selectize.js

How I can load dynamicly (like `$.ajax` or getjson) in selectize options list?

Searched thru the forum, looks like nobody did it this way for some reason (?)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `load(fn)` method is probably what you are looking for.

> Loads options by invoking the the provided function. The function
>   should accept one argument (callback) and invoke the callback with the
>   results once they are available.

Here is the first **[Remote Source](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/)** example:

```
$('#select-repo').selectize({
    valueField: 'url',
    labelField: 'name',
    searchField: 'name',
    create: false,
    render: {
        option: function(item, escape) {
            return '<div>' +
                '<span class="title">' +
                    '<span class="name"><i class="icon ' + (item.fork ? 'fork' : 'source') + '"></i>' + escape(item.name) + '</span>' +
                    '<span class="by">' + escape(item.username) + '</span>' +
                '</span>' +
                '<span class="description">' + escape(item.description) + '</span>' +
                '<ul class="meta">' +
                    (item.language ? '<li class="language">' + escape(item.language) + '</li>' : '') +
                    '<li class="watchers"><span>' + escape(item.watchers) + '</span> watchers</li>' +
                    '<li class="forks"><span>' + escape(item.forks) + '</span> forks</li>' +
                '</ul>' +
            '</div>';
        }
    },
    score: function(search) {
        var score = this.getScoreFunction(search);
        return function(item) {
            return score(item) * (1 + Math.min(item.watchers / 100, 1));
        };
    },
    load: function(query, callback) {
        if (!query.length) return callback();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/' + encodeURIComponent(query),
            type: 'GET',
            error: function() {
                callback();
            },
            success: function(res) {
                callback(res.repositories.slice(0, 10));
            }
        });
    }
});
```